# How to click "save as" dialog window save button system using incognito mode selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

How to click "save as"  dialog window  save button system using incognito mode  selenium c#

Comment: You can't its not a web thing. The dialog belongs to the OS you are running on and needs to be automated by tools that can do such things. There might be drivers for selenium that allow automating desktop/OS UIs but a.) i don't know the platform you are on and b.) i doubt you can use different drivers and get them to work together seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this using the Selenium library. You can add some specific options to the browser to automatically download files. This way you can skip the 'Save As' dialog:

```
    options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", "[DOWNLOAD_FOLDER]");
    options.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
```

Comment: thanks but this is not working when we are executing in incognito mode with latest chrome driver 121

Comment: Are you using a `new ChromeOptions()` and pass this inside the `var driver = new ChromeDriver()`?

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's also not working in non-headless mode with chrome 121.0.6167.140, but it runs fine in headless mode. Have you already tried with

```
options.addArguments("headless");
```

I created an issue in the Selenium project and am waiting for a response.
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/13535

Answer (score 0):

There is one workaround for it.
we need add one key to windows registry inside
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome
PromptForDownloadLocation of type REG_DWORD(32 bit) with value 0